# Double loop for whois.py

Tags: python

I'm using a dictionary with the id as the key and the names as the values. What I'm trying to do is get the names in the values that have the same name in them and put them in a list. Like for example with the name tim:

```
{'id 1': ['timmeh', 'user543', 'tim'], 'id 2': ['tim', 'timmeh', '!anon0543']}
whois_list = ['timmeh', 'user543', 'tim', '!anon0543']
```

The bot would append the names that are not in list yet. This is the code to execute this example:

```
def who(name):
    whois_list = []
    if not any(l for l in whois.whoisDB.values() if name.lower() in l):
        return 'No alias found for <b>%s</b>." % name.title()
    else:
        for l in whois.whoisDB.values():
            if name.lower() in l:
                for names in l:
                    if names not in whois_list
                        whois_list.append(names)
        return "Possible alias found for <b>%s</b>: %s" % (name.title(), whois_list)
```

The issue is: I do not want to have a double loop in this code, but I'm not really sure how to do it, if  it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

A logically equivalent, but shorter and more efficient solution is to use [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) instead of lists.

Your innermost for loop simply extends `whois_list` with every non-duplicate name in `l`. If you originally define `whois_list = set([])` then you can replace the three lines of the inner `for` loop with:

```
whois_list = whois_list.union(l)
```

For example,

```
>>> a = set([1,2,3])
>>> a = a.union([3,4,5])
>>> a
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

You'll notice `a` prints out slightly differently, indicating that it is a `set` instead of a list. If this is a problem, you could convert it right before your `return` statement as in

```
>>> a = list(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```